# How to create JPA class for composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, composite-primary-key

I have table with composite primary keys

> site_Uid       --> from Site table
>   address_Uid       --> from Address
>   table

The below JPA class throws an exception

```
@Entity @IdClass(Site.class)
@Table(name = "site_address")
public class SiteAddress implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7237095501517057347L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "site_uid")
    private int siteUid;
    @Column(name = "address_uid")
    @Id
    private int addressUid;
}
```

Site Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "site")
public class Site implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2059474818667179203L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long siteUid;
    @Column(name = "party_role_uid")
    private int partyRoleUid;
    @Column(name = "site_type_cd")
    private int siteTypeCd;
    @Column(name = "site_name")
    private String siteName;

}
```

Error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to find properties (siteTypeCd, siteName, partyRoleUid) in entity annotated with @IdClass:com.enkindle.model.SiteAddress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a SiteAddressId class with two fields: `int siteUid` and `int addressUid`. Then in SiteAddress do: `@IdClass(SiteAddressId.class)`.

See here for more info: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Composite_Primary_Key_

Comment: Thanks @jonathan-sterling it worked.  SiteAddressId class must implements Serializable.